# jQuery auto click issue

Tags: jquery, navigation, click

I have written code which responds to an image begin clicked by auto clicking a link in the navigation bar by the following code:

```
$('body.node-4 div#block-views-Poster-block_1 img.imagecache-Posters').addClass('manually-linking').click(
function(){
    //$('body.node-4 div#block-menu-primary-links ul li a.menu-224').css('color', 'red').trigger('click');
    $('body.node-4 div#block-menu-primary-links ul li a.menu-224').css('color', 'green').click();
}
);
```

In each case, `.trigger('click')` and `.click()`, I am applying color via CSS to the target link. When the image is clicked, the target link changes color but the navigation to the relevant page never happens.

What might I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wouldn't it be easier to simply redirect to that URL, instead of actually triggering the click?

```
    $(".imagecache-Posters").click(function(){
      var url = $(".menu-224").attr("href");
      location.href = url;
   });
```

I assume you are changing the colour of the link, merely to confirm that it targets properly (as it will of course be reset, when the page reloads).

Comment: Thank you, it sure is easier. I couldn't remember the jquery location redirect syntax so I tried click()

Comment: No problem. In case you are searching for it in the future, the 'location' is not jQuery though, just plain ol' Javascript. ;)

Comment: That's nothing to do with jQuery, that's just JavaScript.